# How to get compiled HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

What I am trying to is to upload Blob file using MVC controller. 
Here is the client code

```
var blob = new Blob('file');
                var fd = new FormData();
                fd.append('blob', blob);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/api/materialList/GenerateReportForMac",
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    data: fd
                });
```

Here is server MVC code

```
public HttpResponseMessage GenerateReportForMac(HttpPostedFileWrapper blob)
{
   // do something here
}
```

Here is routeconfig

```
    routes.MapHttpRoute("GenerateReportForMac", "api/materialList/GenerateReportForMac", new { controller = "MaterialListReportApi", action = "GenerateReportForMac" });
```

However router doesn't map the ajax call to the controller. What did I miss?  I have read a number of similar questions here and on other sites and I followed what is suggested but no luck. I appreciate any tip.

- I have spent enough time to figure out by my self but I couldn't so please don't flag it'

Comment: Please post the whole route config - maybe there is a conflict?  Also, are you using Areas, and is your controller action flagged with `[HttpPost]`

Comment: Yes controller is flagged with HttpPost.

Comment: I can't post the whole config file due to confidentially but there is not conflict.  No I am not using areas.